# How to call SOAP (XML) webservice in javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call asp.net webservice in javascript / Jquery,
i have tried so many examples but unfortunately not succeeded,

here is the code which currently i'm trying,

```
    login("abc@gmail.com", "123456");
    var productServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:50575/Service1.asmx?op=test'; // Preferably write this out from server side

    function login(Email, Password) {
        var soapMessage = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
<soap:Body> \
<login xmlns="http://test.com/"> \
<Email>' + Email + '</Email> \
<Password>' + Password + '</Password> \
</login> \
</soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';

        $.ajax({
            url: productServiceUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapMessage,
            complete: endSaveProduct,
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert(a + "\n"  + b + "\n" + c);
            },
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });

        return false;
    }

    function endSaveProduct(xmlHttpRequest, status) {
        $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
    .find('loginResult')
    .each(function () {
        alert( $(this).find('Message').text());
    });
    }
```

please help me out,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- You are sending a request to different domain so it won't work unless that domain is sending Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or specifically allowing your origin
- You are using `GET` where as you should be using `POST`, because in SOAP over HTTP the envelope must be in the request body.
- <del>jQuery always thinks your data is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` unless you set `processData` to false. Only setting `contentType` will just make the header lie and doesn't actually change this.</del> Actually this is not true if the `data` parameter is a string.

It appears that your target domain is not allowing CORS, so it is impossible to do it directly from client-side. You must use a server proxy to do the request.

If they allowed CORS, you would do it like so:

```
var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
                    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">\
                      <soap12:Body>\
                        <login xmlns="http://tastygo.com/">\
                          <BBMID>string</BBMID>\
                          <Email>string</Email>\
                          <Password>string</Password>\
                        </login>\
                      </soap12:Body>\
                    </soap12:Envelope>';

$.ajax( "http://m.allaccesstnt.com/AATnTWebservices/Webservices/Userwebservice.asmx", {

    contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST", //important
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapMessage

});
```

But this will not work because the server does not allow OPTIONS, which the browser must use to determine whether a cross-origin request is allowed:

```
OPTIONS http://m.allaccesstnt.com/AATnTWebservices/Webservices/Userwebservice.asmx 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

The second problem is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.allaccesstnt.com/AATnTWebservices/Webservices/Userwebservice.asmx. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: So have you any solution bro?

Comment: What do you mean? I just said it's impossible because of the same-origin security policy. The server must allow it with a header which I cannot control.

Comment: @SohailAhmad consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. You can do so by clicking the white checkmark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

just add http://m.allaccesstnt.com/AATnTWebservices/Webservices/Userwebservice.asmx/**test**
&
Add Header in web server side