# SOAP WEB SERVICE Not Allowed Error Security Setting prevent to access this method

Tags: internet-explorer, soap, adobe

I'm using the below method to access my web service it's working fine if I'm accessing my web service from the Adobe reader but If i'm uisng it from Internet explorer it's give me the error

"Not Allowed Error Security Setting prevent to access this method". I have to use this from Internet explorer.

```
enter code here var cURL ="http://localhost:port/WebService.asmx?WSDL";

                var oParam = "Location";
                SOAP.wireDump = true;
               var oAuthenticator = { UsePlatformAuth:"true"};
               var ver = SOAPVersion.version_1_2;
               var oRequest = { soapValue:"<Query xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>" +
                      "<QueryName>" + oParam + "</QueryName>" +"</Query>"}; 
              var cAction = "http://tempuri.org/Query";

                var response = SOAP.request(

                  {
                    cURL: cURL,

                      oRequest: oRequest,

                    cAction: cAction,

                oAuthenticate:oAuthenticator,

                         bEncoded:false,

                     cVersion:ver});
```

I have tried Soap. connect method and getting the same error.

I have added the WSDL site in IE as trued sites as well as added the site the adobe setting.

Comment: Whether you are using some jquery plugin to call the SOAP web service? If you are using the Jquery plugin, please check the browser compatibility. And. can you post enough code to reproduce the problem? Here are some related links about using ajax to call the web service, you could refer to them: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815985/) and [Link 3](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/calling-webservice-using-ajax-jquery-with-soap-message-creat/)

Comment: thanks for your help. Adobe does not support Ajax

Comment: I did not get any answer yet. I still looking it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369830/soap-web-service-call-from-adobe-acrobat-pro-java-script

Comment: Please check the following threads: [thread 1](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-to-use-app-opendoc-api-in-acrord-reader/m-p/9680745?page=1), [thread 2](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/security-settings-error-with-web-service/m-p/10886085?page=1)  and [thread 3](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/ajax-call-on-acrobat-form-by-javascript/m-p/8599246?page=1), I found these threads from the Adobe Acrobat forum, it seems that this issue is related to Adobe Acrobat, please contact them. Besides, try to open IE browser IE Options, in the Security tab try to disable Protected mode.

Comment: Thanks for that I have checked all the treads.